# PostgreSQL fails on boot, but works fine after logging in

Tags: postgresql, debian-squeeze

I'm not sure if my problem started after update.
I'm running Debian Squeeze and postgresql-8.4(8.4.12-0squeeze1).
On startup or after reboot, I noticed that my PostgreSQL database service fails.
However, when I'll login with root, the service is already running, and I can execute /etc/init.d/postgresql restart in a conosle, and it works fine.
What could cause this error message?

here is my log from /var/log/boot

```
...
Tue Jul 24 09:40:23 2012: + pg_ctlcluster 8.4 main start
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + ERRMSG=The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + res=1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + set -e
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 0 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 2 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + status=1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -ne 0 -a -n The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_failure_msg The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -n The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_begin_msg The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ...
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -z The ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + echo -n The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ...
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: ...+ log_end_msg 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -z 1 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + retval=1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_end_msg_pre 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + :
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_use_fancy_output
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -t 1 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ xlinux != x ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ xlinux != xdumb ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -z ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + FANCYTTY=1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + true
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + RED=^[[31m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + YELLOW=^[[33m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput op
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + NORMAL=^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 0 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 255 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /bin/echo -e  ^[[31mfailed!^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012:  ^[[31mfailed!^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_end_msg_post 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + :
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + return 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + true
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_end_msg 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -z 1 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + retval=1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_end_msg_pre 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + :
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_use_fancy_output
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -t 1 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ xlinux != x ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ xlinux != xdumb ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -x /usr/bin/expr ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ -z 1 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + true
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + true
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + RED=^[[31m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + YELLOW=^[[33m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /usr/bin/tput op
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + NORMAL=^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 0 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + [ 1 -eq 255 ]
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + /bin/echo -e  ^[[31mfailed!^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012:  ^[[31mfailed!^[[39;49m
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + log_end_msg_post 1
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + :
Tue Jul 24 09:41:04 2012: + return 1
```

here is log from /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log

```
2012-07-25 10:40:41 CEST LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2012-07-25 10:40:41 CEST LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  shutting down
2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST LOG:  database system is shut down
2012-07-25 10:46:18 CEST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2012-07-25 10:45:46 CEST
2012-07-25 10:48:45 CEST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2012-07-25 10:48:45 CEST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: The log file you've posted is not particularly useful. Please post your *postgres* log file (often `/var/log/postgresql.log` but Debian may put it somewhere else).  Also please put the relevant section of the log file in your question - Links to storage services eventually break, which will make your question useless to future users.  Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion is well taken.
I have edited the question and added the log from /var/log/postgressql/postgressql-8.4-main.log.
I have not included this log previously because I thought there was nothing useful in it.

Comment: Maybe one of data partitions/tablespaces are not available when the server starts initially. Like disks mounted over iscsi or usb.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two log files (and the description at the top of your question that I missed when I read this last night :x), your startup script has a bug that causes it to think Postgres has failed to start when it is in fact up and running (`database system is ready to accept connections`).

If I had to guess I would say the bug is in `pg_ctlcluster`, which from your boot log above seems to be returning `1` ("Other failures") even though the DB server is running.  Without seeing the `pg_ctlcluster` script I can't tell you what the problem is, but since that script is supplied by the Debian folks my answer would be the same: Report this as a bug to Debian so they can fix their script to correctly determine if Postgres was successfully started or not.

<sub>(Sorry my answer isn't more helpful, but `pg_ctlcluster` is a Debianism. Even if we look at the script, figure out what's wrong, and tell you how to fix it the package manager will overwrite it the next time Debian ships a Postgres upgrade and it will start reporting false failures again...)</sub>